# Backbone.js: Decoding the Fetched Data

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

Using `Backbone.js` I need to perform the following tasks:

1) fetch the data from the server
2) `Decoding the Fetched Data`  (perform some operation on this data)
3) Inject these data to my view and then my HTML template

About the task number two (Decoding the Fetched Data ),
what is the best place/way/pattern to make it in a MVC context?

---

Some of the data to encode are about the rights and look like this:

```
READ               = 0x01,
CREATE_USER        = 0x08,
CREATE_WORKSPACE   = 0x10,
UPDATE             = 0x20,
```

I need to encode them making Bit Operations with a mask.

Comment: There's no way to answer this unless you describe the data.

Comment: @Chris I added some info about the data to encode.

Comment: Your data is encoded *how*?  Are you making requests to the server and getting back byte streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide your own [`parse`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) implementation in the model:

> **parse** `model.parse(response)`
>
> **parse** is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in `fetch`, and `save`. The function is passed the raw `response` object, and should return the attributes hash to be set on the model.

So you'd have something like this:

```
parse: function(response) {
    var parsed_response = _(response).clone();
    // do your bit wrangling on parsed_response and remove what you don't want...
    return parsed_response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best place to do this within a MV* framework like Backbone.js would likely be a model. The Backbone model can be more of a presentation model in the Model View Presenter sense which contains shared presentation logic in the form of computed properties. If the derived property is only ever used in a single view, then an argument can be made for just sticking it into the view.

One thing you may want to do is to bind the underlying property to the computed property so that any changes are automatically reflected.